# WMS GetFeatureInfo request with buffer doesn't return any result (OpenLayers/MapServer)

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

I'm using OpenLayers 4 to build a GetFeatureInfo URL with a buffer parameter to a WMS layer in MapServer in order to find the closest feature of the layer given some specific coordinates.

The problem is that the request never returns any result at all. So I don't know if there is something wrong in my code or I'm missing something.

Here is my code explained:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/mapwms/REDIAM_PPHH_2012?',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'MSPF_POLY'},
        serverType: 'mapserver',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    })
});

// I create the layer only for requesting purpose so I don't add it to the map.

var coordinates = [311618.514508171, 4040090.26715453];

var srs = this.map_.getProjection().code; //"EPSG:25830"

const getFeatureInfoParams = {
        'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/plain', //or application/vnd.ogc.gml
        'FEATURE_COUNT': 1,
        'SRS': srs,
        'Buffer': 10;
};

var viewResolution = this.map_.getMapImpl().getView().getResolution(); 
// 353.3212194629518

var urlToRequest = layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(coordinates, viewResolution, srs, 
getFeatureInfoParams);

return urlToRequest;
// urlToRequest is ==> http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/mapwms/REDIAM_PPHH_2012?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=MSPF_POLY&LAYERS=MSPF_POLY&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fplain&FEATURE_COUNT=1&SRS=EPSG%3A25830&Buffer=10&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A25830&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=293775.7929252919%2C4022247.5455716513%2C329461.2360910501%2C4057932.988737409
```

I have seen that it always return I=50/J=50 and perhaps this could be the problem I don't know. It is that correct?

The pixel coordinates shouldn't be different in different bounding boxes values per request?

Comment: Any errors in the debugger console? Errors in debugger network?

Comment: I don't believe that MapServer supports "buffer" https://www.mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html. Buffer does not belong to WMS standard. GeoServer supports buffer as a vendor option. In MapServer LAYER-TOLERANCE https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html has the same effect but it may not be possible to give tolerance as a variable.

Comment: @TomazicM unfortunately not.

Comment: @user30184 are you sure about that? I thought that option too but I have another layer in my map apparently in the same Mapserver namespace and if you substitute in the URL of the request the layer **MSPF_POLY** for **unidades_hidrogeologicas** it returns the closest feature in the layer as expected.

I have never work to deep with MapServer I have always used Geoserver, could it be possible that you have to configure in every layer that you publish the BUFFER option?

Comment: `I have seen that it always return I=50/J=50 and perhaps this could be the problem I don't know. It is that correct?` Seems odd for the point you click on your image to always be at a location 50 pixels down and 50 across

Comment: In MapServer the service provider sets the tolerance (buffer) for a clicked point to provide data, a user can't buffer the clicked point

Comment: @nmtoken The I=50/J=50 was weird. I've tried to add the layer to the map and it seems that now the I/J is getting different pixels values maybe it was because the layer needs to be added to the map, not sure. On the other hand, do you mean that you can never apply a buffer in request for the clicked point in MapServer GetFeatureInfo?

Comment: `do you mean that you can never apply a buffer in request for the clicked point in MapServer GetFeatureInfo`  well, as already mentioned the [WMS specification](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416)  doesn't have a buffer parameter (for GetMap or GetFeatureInfo operations) so specifying a buffer& is I think unlikely to work (be ignored), I note though that MapServer does have a BUFFER variable listed in its [CGI controls](https://mapserver.org/cgi/controls.html) so it's possible you can get that to work for you.

Comment: Another possibility is to specify tolerance as a [runtime substitution](https://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html#runsub).  Which assumes you are in control of the server.

Comment: @nmtoken unfortunately I don't have control of the server so I cant' specify tolerance as a runtime substitution as you mentioned. It is necessary have control of the server to do the CGI controls approach for the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Use 'radius' instead of 'buffer':

http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/mapwms/REDIAM_PPHH_2012?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&QUERY_LAYERS=MSPF_POLY&LAYERS=MSPF_POLY&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fplain&FEATURE_COUNT=1&SRS=EPSG%3A25830&radius=13&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A25830&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=293775.7929252919%2C4022247.5455716513%2C329461.2360910501%2C4057932.988737409